# How to get database information from Joomla category

Tags: php, mysql, database, joomla

I know how I can retrieve all information from a article in the database. I am trying to do the same thing for a category. And just for clarification, I am talking about when view is equal to category (index.php?option=com_content&view=category). Below is how I can retrieve any information for a article, when I am on a article page, I want to do the same exact thing, but when I am on a category page. Thanks!

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$articleId = $input->getInt('id');
$article = JTable::getInstance('content');
$article->load($articleId);
$articleTitle = $article->get('title');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the view is currently on `category` by using the following:

```
$input  = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$option = $input->get('option', '');
$view   = $input->get('view', '');

if ($option == 'com_content' && $view == 'category')
{
    // Do something
}
```

You will see that I'm also checking for the `option` (component in use) as other components use a category view.

Comment: That is not what I was asking... maybe I did not explain it well. I already know how to get the view and all that good stuff. I am talking about when I am on a category page (like this index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=8) I want to be able to get the Title, Description, Published, etc... (all the information that is in the categories table in the database).

Comment: Ahh I see. Try asking your question over at [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com) where it will probably get more attention ;)

Comment: Did you just not read my question or did it not make sense? Don't wanna post it again and no one understands.

Comment: All good, I will try posting it there, but will it be considered double post?

Comment: It will be fine. You can always close this question if you like after you've posted it on JSE

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was change content to category and I was able to access all data within the category table using the same method I did with the content.

```
$input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$catId = $input->getInt('id');
$cat = JTable::getInstance('category');
$cat->load($catId);
```

Comment: Please add some explination to your answer to avoid deletion

Comment: Is that good? Not really sure what to add, cause I did not do much but just change content to category. Any tips would be appreciated and thanks for letting me know to put a explanation.